# Yeoman / Grunt not compiling Compass

Tags: javascript, build-process, yeoman, gruntjs

Has anyone come across an issue using compass with yeoman and grunt where the stylesheets are not being compiled in their build. I'm new at this and trying to really understand whats going on behind the scenes. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
  'use strict';
  var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
  var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
  };

  module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    };

    try {
      yeomanConfig.app = require('./component.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
    } catch (e) {}

    grunt.initConfig({
      yeoman: yeomanConfig,
      watch: {
        coffee: {
          files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
          tasks: ['coffee:dist']
        },
        coffeeTest: {
          files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
          tasks: ['coffee:test']
        },
        compass: {
          files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
          tasks: ['compass']
        },
        livereload: {
          files: [
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
            '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            'images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
          ],
          tasks: ['livereload']
        }
      },
      connect: {
        options: {
          port: 9000,
          // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
          hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
          options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
              return [
                lrSnippet,
                mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
              ];
            }
          }
        },
        test: {
          options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
              return [
                mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                mountFolder(connect, 'test')
              ];
            }
          }
        }
      },
      open: {
        server: {
          url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
        }
      },
      clean: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            dot: true,
            src: [
              '.tmp',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
              '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
            ]
          }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
      },
      jshint: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      karma: {
        unit: {
          configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
          singleRun: true
        }
      },
      coffee: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
            dest: '.tmp/scripts',
            ext: '.js'
          }]
        },
        test: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'test/spec',
            src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
            dest: '.tmp/spec',
            ext: '.js'
          }]
        }
      },
      compass: {
        options: {
          sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
          cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
          imagesDir: 'images',
          javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
          importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
          relativeAssets: true
        },
        dist: {},
        server: {
          options: {
            debugInfo: true
          }
        }
      },
      concat: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
              '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
              '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      },
      usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
          dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        }
      },
      imagemin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
          }]
        }
      },
      cssmin: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
              '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
              '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      htmlmin: {
        dist: {
          options: {
            /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
            // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
            //collapseWhitespace: true,
            collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
            removeAttributeQuotes: true,
            removeRedundantAttributes: true,
            useShortDoctype: true,
            removeEmptyAttributes: true,
            removeOptionalTags: true*/
          },
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
          }]
        }
      },
      cdnify: {
        dist: {
          html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
      },
      ngmin: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
            src: '*.js',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
          }]
        }
      },
      uglify: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      rev: {
        dist: {
          files: {
            src: [
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
              'images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      copy: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            src: [
              '*.{ico,txt}',
              '.htaccess',
              'components/**/*',
              'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
              'styles/fonts/*'
            ]
          }]
        }
      }
    });

    grunt.renameTask('regarde', 'watch');

    grunt.registerTask('server', [
      'clean:server',
      'coffee:dist',
      'compass:server',
      'livereload-start',
      'connect:livereload',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
      'clean:server',
      'coffee',
      'compass',
      'connect:test',
      'karma'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
      'clean:dist',
      // 'jshint',
      // 'test',
      // 'coffee',
      'compass:dist',
      'useminPrepare',
      'imagemin',
      'cssmin',
      'htmlmin',
      'concat',
      'copy',
      // 'cdnify',
      'ngmin',
      'uglify',
      'rev',
      'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
  };
```

Comment: What's the error, when you run `grunt compass`?

Comment: I actually found the issue. It seems that useminPrepare rewrites my concat but incorrectly. This 'dist/styles/main.css': [ 'app/styles/main.css' ] should be ignored but im not sure how to do that :(

Comment: Nevermind this was answered in this github thread: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/193

Comment: thanks alvincrespo! the gruntfile change in the github thread was what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution of the provided github issue:

> I edited the grunt build task and moved `'concat'` to before `'imagemin'` and now grunt build works properly and main.css is properly generated.